# trying to load a datatable into a datagridview causes crashes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, datagridview, datatable

I've got a simple DB application that allows a user to search a MSSQL table on some specific terms, then export the results found to a log file.

I ran into a strange bug that would cause the application to freeze, but only if I was running the "Release" build and never when I was running the Debug build inside of visual studio.  I can run all sorts of queries without a problem.  However if the very first query I run returns 0 results, then the very next query that returns any result will always fail when trying to load the results from the datatable into the datagrid view.

I'm pretty sure it's crashing because of me not following a best practice on my side, but I'm not entirely sure why.

Here's the truncated pieces of code.

```
//Declared in the start of the class
DataTable DBResults = new DataTable();


//This is run inside of a method called by a background worker.
DBResults.Clear();

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, SQLConnection);
SqlConnection SQLCon = new SqlConnection(getConnectionString());

//This is wrapped inside a try/catch/finally.
SQLCon.Open();
da.Fill(DBResults);
SQLCon.Close();

//Finally, push the data into the Datagridview inside of the form.
//This is the line that will always freeze the app when running a Final build, but not a debug build.
dataGridView_Results.DataSource = new DataView(DBResults);

this.dataGridView_Results.Refresh();


//I discovered that if I changed the crashing line to copy instead, it won't crash:
dataGridView_Results.DataSource = new DataView(DBResults.Copy());
```

I'm assuming that it's because the Datasource still has a pointer at DbResults.  But it's strange that it doesn't cause an issue if I have results, only if the very first search returns 0 results.  It's visual studio 2012 .NET 4 if that makes a difference at all.

Comment: Have you tried dataGridView_Results.DataSource = DBResults?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You mention a backgroundworker, which makes it likely that you are multi-threading. Could you also show the call you are making. Chances are that you are manipulating the UI from another thread.

Answer (score 0):

Etan, you should assign the data table directly to the datasource property of the datagridview without doing the new. It should be like this:

```
dataGridView_Results.DataSource = DBResults;
```

I really don't know much about the copy property of the line below.